# Mongoose Schema pagination typing using mongoose-paginate-ts

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, pagination, es6-modules

**EDIT FIXED** :

What I onited say in my initial post is that I was exporting the `mongoose-pagination-ts` function & interface from a global file, and then importing it in my schema files to use it. However, it appears that I need to import the module directly in each schema file in order for it to work, Interface cannot be export in a file and import in another, comming from a node_module in CommonJS (Apparently, not sure if it's the correct reason)

---

I'm facing the following issue :

The module [mongoose-pagination-ts](https://github.com/IGLU-Agency/mongoose-paginate-ts) explains as follow :

```js
import { mongoosePagination, Pagination } from "mongoose-paginate-ts";
type User = mongoose.Document & {
  username: String,
  accounts: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId]
};
const userSchema = new Schema({
  username: String,
  accounts: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: "Account" }]
});
userSchema.plugin(mongoosePagination);
const User: Pagination<User> = mongoose.model<User, Pagination<User>>("User", userSchema);

//User.paginate()
```

The build passes with no issue, but when I execute the server in development mode using the following command I have the bellow issue :

`nodemon --ext 'ts,js,cjs,json' --ignore 'tests/' --exec 'ts-node-esm src/index.ts'`

```js
import { mongoosePagination, Pagination } from "mongoose-paginate-ts";
                             ^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Named export 'Pagination' not found. The requested module 'mongoose-paginate-ts' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:
import pkg from 'mongoose-paginate-ts';
const { mongoosePagination, Pagination } = pkg;
    at ModuleJob._instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:124:21)
    at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:190:5)
```

tsconfig.js

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "ESNext" /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */,
    "module": "ESNext" /* Specify what module code is generated. */,
    "rootDir": "./src" /* Specify the root folder within your source files. */,
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext" /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */,
    "baseUrl": "./src" /* Specify the base directory to resolve non-relative module names. */,
    "outDir": "build",
    "types": ["node", "mocha"] /* Specify type package names to be included without being referenced in a source file. */,
    "allowJs": true /* Allow JavaScript files to be a part of your program. Use the 'checkJS' option to get errors from these files. */,
    "checkJs": false /* Enable error reporting in type-checked JavaScript files. */,
    "esModuleInterop": true /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */,
    "strict": false /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
    "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "swc": true
  },
  "exclude": ["tests", "node_modules"]
}
```

Any solution is welcomed, thanks !

The error is clear : the module is exported as a CommonJS module and the proposed solution should work, however, the `Pagination` interface cannot be destructured as explained :

```js
import pkg from 'mongoose-paginate-ts';
const { mongoosePagination, Pagination } = pkg; // Pagination is not found
```